# How to execute batch file remotly over non domain workgroup Win XP network as administrator?

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, workgroup

I need to execute a batch file *remotely* run as administrator over a workgroup win XP network.

Is there a way to do that?

I don't want make domain for that — I'm just looking for a solution as stated in the title!

How to execute a batch file remotely over non-domain workgroup Win XP network as administrator?

The reason that I want to do is enable WMI services and add rows in FIREWALL over the network!

When Googling I found remote shell but I faced this error:

```
C:\>winrm quickconfig
WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message = Access is denied.

Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

look for sysinternals psexec tool

Comment: i don't wanna excecute any file on remotes computer but psexec tool is a client server app

Comment: since when is psexec client server? - you simply launch psexec on computer and let it connect to another machine and exekuce something there (in your case the WMI enabling script) - where's the problem?